# Isotope - Make a responsive masonry element full-width

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

Consider the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/schmidjon/6Z3sn/

It displays a very cool masonry effect with Isotope. If you drag the container handles or resize the window, you'll notice how the elements get a responsive width based on a combination of CSS and Javascript.

Depending on different breakpoints, the script let's you define the column number you need for different devices:

```
var w = $container.width(), 
    columnNum = 1,
    columnWidth = 0;
    if (w > 1200) {
        columnNum  = 5;
    } else if (w > 900) {
        columnNum  = 4;
    } else if (w > 600) {
        columnNum  = 3;
    } else if (w > 300) {
        columnNum  = 2;
    }
```

In a 4 columns grid, to get an element to be 2 columns wide, thus 50% wide, the CSS needed for an item would be:

```
.example .item-w2 {
    width: 40%;
}
```

So the following javascript part transforms it to pixels:

```
multiplier_w = $item.attr('class').match(/item-w(\d)/),
multiplier_h = $item.attr('class').match(/item-h(\d)/),
width = multiplier_w ? columnWidth*multiplier_w[1]-4 : columnWidth-4,
height = multiplier_h ? columnWidth*multiplier_h[1]*0.5-4 : columnWidth*0.5-4;
```

Now, I've modified this same script to fit my needs, in this case a 100% width module on a 4 columns grid, so now, if you take a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmf8xfch/1/

...you will notice I modified the CSS to get the desired width on certain elements, so I just added another class:

```
.example .item-w3 {
    width: 80%;
    background: #ED9393;
}
```

So, that 80% width gives you an actual 100% with the javascript calculation.

The thing is, at smaller resolutions (below 400px wide) the element is bigger than its container and screen. It overflows to the right.

Everything has to do with the following javascript part:

```
width = multiplier_w ? columnWidth*multiplier_w[1]-4 : columnWidth-4
```

But I'm not sure I understand what's going on there to change the code myself and get that element to be 100% screen-wide on responsive views.

Comment: Hey! Have you found an answer to this yet? I just stumbled upon your question and gladly took up that initial script too, it's very cool. However I have a different problem - how did you manage to `'$(window).smartresize(isotope);'` work? smartresize isn't supported in the new version of isotope anymore apparently. I tried to use `$('.example').isotope('layout');` instead to initiate a resizing of the elements but it doesn't work. If I change windowsizes I have to reload to have it fit the new browserwindow.